# Shell add day to date saved in parameter

Tags: shell, date, datetime, unix, time

Hoping someone can help me work out what on earth is happening here.

I've got a script which receives a date as a parameter in this format "2016-09-01 00:00:00" and should create another variable containing the date for one day in the future, code is below

```
    currentDate=$1
    currentDate=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" -d "$currentDate")
    nextDate=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" -d "$currentDate + 1 day")
    echo $currentDate
    echo $nextDate
```

Sometimes this works perfectly fine for example

2016-09-01 00:00:00 - date given as parameter

2016-09-02 00:00:00 - output for next day

But sometimes it'll only add 23 hours depending on the date provided

2016-02-01 00:00:00 - date given as parameter

2016-02-01 23:00:00 - output for next day

if I change the nextDay variable to add three days as below

```
     nextDate=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" -d "$currentDate + 3 day")
```

it gives the output as below adding only 21 hours instead of 3 days

2016-02-01 00:00:00 - date given as parameter

2016-02-01 21:00:00 - output for next day

Could someone help me understand why this is happening, is it related to timezones?

Comment: What is your timezone?

Comment: GMT London/Europe

Answer (score 0):

The reason appears to be how difficult it is to do free-form date parsing:

A baseline date: (I'm in the America/Toronto time zone)

```
$ date -d "2016-11-06 01:00:00" "+%F %T%z"
2016-11-06 01:00:00-0400
```

Try adding a day

```
$ date -d "2016-11-06 01:00:00 + 1 day" "+%F %T%z"
2016-11-06 19:00:00-0500
```

Hmm, that's strange, looks like it's adding a day but then expressing it as midnight, then subtracting 5 hours.

Let's try adding a day to just the date part

```
$ date -d "2016-11-06 + 1 day 01:00:00" "+%F %T%z"
2016-11-07 01:00:00-0500
```

That looks better.

In your script try this:

```bsh
read current_date current_time < <(date -d "$1" +"%F %T%z")
echo "$current_date $current_time"
next_day=$(date -d "$current_date + 1 day $current_time" +"%F %T%z")
echo "$next_day"
three_days=$(date -d "$current_date + 3 day $current_time" +"%F %T%z")
echo "$three_days"
```